# How can I efficiently change the underlying list of an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have created a CustomArrayAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter, and initialized it with an ArrayList `list1`. Upon a user action, I create a second list, `list2`, that takes a few moments to populate. Upon its successful creation, I want the CustomArrayAdapter to use `list2` as the data source instead.

For example:

```
list2 = new ArrayList<>();
//actions that populate list2
list1 = list2;
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But, of course, `customAdapter` does not update because it still looks at the memory address that `list1` **used** to point to, so it still uses the old data.

What would be the best way to efficiently change the list my `customAdapter` is using for data? For example, I could do:

```
list1.clear();
list1.addAll(list2);
```

but this would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: well, it is not so *horribly inefficient* ... but of course the first solution will be better ... so solution is - to write a own adapter based on BaseAdapter ... *But, of course, customAdapter does not update because it still looks at the memory address that list1 used to point to, so it still uses the old data.* ... yes, the ArayAdapter constructor copy input list into new list

Comment: Did you try `customAdapter.invalidate()` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: @joaquin huh? it doesn't matter ...

Comment: I am guessing you are going to use your `ArrayAdapter` with a `ListView`. I would suggest you stop and use a `RecyclerView Adapter`. Most of it is done for you and it is apart of the new APIs. Follow the MVC pattern: http://blogs.techsmith.com/inside-techsmith/devcorner-android-lollipop/.

Comment: Sometimes it works... Am I wrong?

Comment: programmer doesn't says: *Sometimes it works...* ...  *Am I wrong?* yes ... it works if you add stupid extention to this class and duplicating underlaying data(of course if you wana do this it is always better to extend BaseAdapter) ...

Comment: @Selvin, I have already written my own custom ArrayAdapter. How does this help me? Thanks :)

Comment: @joaquin, this would not solve the problem, because the customAdapter is still not looking at the `list2` data.

Comment: Thanks @Jared but I'm not able to update to RecyclerView at this point.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Selvin. I take it back. You're right

Comment: @TaylorKline It sounds like you haven't started. Prevent yourself from doing double work, it takes seconds to upgrade. https://github.com/jaredsburrows/AndroidGradleTemplate/blob/master/Example-AllLibraries/src/main/java/burrows/apps/example/template/adapter/BaseAdapter.java

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/bb4f8aebb129f1db9420 <= now you can access to list passed to the constructor directly and then call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh the ListView... but you don't have default filtering ...